# .htaccess Redirecting to wrong page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is the original URL

```
http://localhost/naranjeshaltd/index.php?url=home
```

and I want redirect it to

```
http://localhost/naranjeshaltd/home
```

I have tried this htaccess code but it is redirecting page to *`http://localhost/xampp`*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /naranjeshaltd
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

But when I use this htaccess code everything working fine

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /naranjeshaltd
RewriteRule home$ index.php?url=home
```

but its a static method, how can I do this for all pages?

Comment: Doe you really want to redirect the requests or do you want to be able to access `/naranjeshajtd/index.php?url=*` via `/naranjeshaltd/*`?  There is a difference here.  My guess is that you want the latter (a clean URL solution).

Comment: do you mean like `[A-Za-z]` ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see 2 main issues here:

1. You should avoid redirecting to `index.php` for real file/dir/link.
2. Don't use `/` as the starting slash in target URL otherwise it will not be relative your RewriteBase

Change your code to this:

```
RewriteBase /naranjeshaltd/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: yeah... its working!!! great. thankyou very much anubhava. can you please give me some explanation about this code so I can better understand?

Comment: @SumitBijvani: I just added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /naranjeshaltd
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /naranjeshaltd/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: its return **500 Internal Server Error**